# WF 4, WCF, cancel running workflow

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, cancellation

Currently have a simple workflow exposed as a service endpoint. The service correlates on the workflow instance id and everything works as expected (2 service calls available ReceiveBegin, Execute).

My problem is that I would like the user to be able to cancel the long running part of the workflow by calling another Receive on the workflow. Have had a look at the `WorkflowApplication.Cancel` but as I am running this as a WCF service it doesn't seem to be available.

Documentation seems a bit light on this area and most HOL and examples focus on console apps hosting the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With workflow services the [Workflow Control Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358723.aspx) and [WorkflowControlClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.workflowcontrolclient.aspx) will allow you to cancel workflow instances.

Comment: But how do you add a workflow control endpoint to a service created from the "WCF Workflow Service Application" project template. It does not insert a `<service>` node into the web.config where the endpoint could be added. I've spent days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is shown in the [WF4 Batch Job example](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wf4BatchJob)

Comment: Thanks Ron I will take a look at this, sorry I have taken a while to reply to your post I have been deep in the WF for a couple of weeks.