# Cancel/Stop Workflow in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have long running workflow which runs for 3-5 minutes; I want to give flexibility to end user to Cancel/Stop/Abort workflow while workflow is in execution. How can I do this ?

Ocean

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your workflow execution environment. If you are using the WorkflowApplication it has methods to control a workflow. If your are using the WorkflowServiceHost there is a  Workflow Control Endpoint with a client that will let you do so. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456761/wf-4-wcf-cancel-running-workflow/5458149#5458149) for the WCF option.